# Android - ListView items wont display object data

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

Im using a BaseAdapter and passing to it a List of objects that have their own data sets. In each row of the listview Id like an image, description, ect. of each object. When I use the BaseAdapter as I have it set now I dont get any errors and Ive checked over and over in the debugger and logcat that my List of objects are valid and not null. But for some reason the list builds with the correct number of objects but not one of the ImageViews, TextViews, or anything else takes on any of the data. The only thing in each row is the same default data I use in the xml layout for the list row. Its like the call to each View's set method is either being ignored for some reason or the content for the view is being passed to another context onscreen or something wacky. Anyway heres my BaseAdapter class:

```
 class MaItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        List<Ma> mas = null;
        Context cntx = null;
        //LayoutInflater myInflater;
        int itemPosition =0;
        ViewHolder holder;

        public MarkItemAdapter(Activity cntx,List<Ma> mas){
            super();
            this.mas = mas;
            this.cntx = cntx;
            //myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(cntx);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mas.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mas.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            itemPosition = position;
            RelativeLayout rl = null;
            Mark ma = mas.get(itemPosition);
            if (convertView==null) {
                rl = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(cntx).inflate(
                        R.layout.ma_row_item, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                try{
                holder.description = (TextView) rl.findViewById(R.id.ma_description);
                holder.distance = (TextView) rl.findViewById(R.id.ma_distance);
                holder.ma_image = (ImageView) rl.findViewById(R.id.ma_image);
                holder.view_ma = (ImageButton) rl.findViewById(R.id.view_ma);
                holder.rate_ma = (RatingBar) rl.findViewById(R.id.rate_ma);
                holder.description.setText(ma.title);
                holder.distance.setText(ma.getDistanceString());
                holder.view_ma.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    //dostuff
                }

            });
            if(ma.textImg!=null &&
                    !ma.textImg.isRecycled()){
            holder.ma_image.setImageBitmap(ma.textImg);
            }else{
                holder.ma_image.setImageResource(R.raw.skyma);
            }}catch(NullPointerException e){}
            }else{
                rl = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
            }


        //add logic for rating bar

            return rl;
        }


    }

//convenience class to create views 
    private class ViewHolder{
        ImageView ma_image;
        TextView description;
        TextView distance;
        ImageButton view_ma;
        RatingBar rate_ma;

        public ViewHolder(){
            ma_image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            description = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            distance = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            view_ma = new ImageButton(getApplicationContext());
            rate_ma = new RatingBar(getApplicationContext());
        }
    }

}
```

Ive run through a few tutorials and they work fine but when I use this set up in my own app its a no go. Some help in the right direction would be awesome. One other thing I should mention is that if I push on the rating bar i see the same rating pop up every four or five rows. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: are you sure you don't get a NPE in your try-catch block? if so you just ignore it. also it looks like you don't do anything with the convertView if it's not null (besides casting it to a RelativeLayout) you need to set the content of you image and textviews everytime the getView method is called

Comment: Yeah occasionally I get an NPE when Im trying to setText from the object which wasnt null when I looked at it in the debugger so I just used that as a bandaid for now

Comment: there you go, once you get the NPE at holder.description.setText(ma.title) your convertView will not be null for the next time your adapter getView is called and you never set all the values again. btw: do you really have to initialize the views in your ViewHolder? your setting them via findViewById() - maybe you should move the whole code for that to your ViewHolder constructor

Comment: So in other words move all the findViewById() calls to my ViewHolder constructor? I dont have to do that but in the debugger I would see that the TextView was coming up null even though there was no NPE. Ill move my initialization of those fields into the constructor to see what happens and post back in a couple minutes.

Comment: Well I removed my try catch and moved the findViewById calls but Im still getting the NPE when I first setText when ConvertView==null.

Comment: can you check if inflating your layout works (by looking at the child elements of rl during debugging) and if you then can get your 5 different views using findViewById - or is the problem that either ma or ma.title is null?

Comment: I checked in the debugger and the inflater isnt null and neither are the ma objects. It just fails on the setText and gives me a null pointer. When I debug I can see that no matter what I do the TextView comes up null when I create it in the ViewHolder class I created. I even got rid of all my code I had and started over using something I got out of a book which wasnt to far off from what I had  in the example up top but I still get the same error at the same spot. For some reason the textview just wont instantiate and it comes up null.

Comment: Believe it or not I had used name instead of id when I declared all the row views in xml. What a pain in the ass over a syntax error lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your getView method...this is how my custom adapters are setup.

```
itemPosition = position;
View v = convertView;
Mark ma = mas.get(itemPosition);

if (v == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) cntx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ma_row_item, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
}

holder.description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ma_description);
holder.distance = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ma_distance);
holder.ma_image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ma_image);
holder.view_ma = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.view_ma);
holder.rate_ma = (RatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.rate_ma);
holder.description.setText(ma.title);
holder.distance.setText(ma.getDistanceString());
holder.view_ma.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //dostuff
    }

});

if(ma.textImg!=null && !ma.textImg.isRecycled()) {
    holder.ma_image.setImageBitmap(ma.textImg);
} else {
    holder.ma_image.setImageResource(R.raw.skyma);
}
```

If that doesn't work, I could also suggest just initializing your individual views from within the getView method body instead of in ViewHolder. Something like:

```
TextView description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ma_description);
description.setText(ma.title);
```

Comment: nope that didnt work either. I still get the same nullpointer that I was getting before. For some reason it just ignores the instantiating of any views inside getview